# How to get value from file in sh?

Tags: bash, unix, sh

### Setup:

File `a` contains:

```
22
```

File `b` contains:

```
12
```

I have shell **script** `1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=$(< a)
b=$(< b)
echo $(($a*$b)) > c
```

The script should get values from file `a` and `b`, multiply them `*`, and save to file `c`.
However after setting permission `$ chmod a+rx 1.sh` and running it `$ ./1.sh` it returns an **error**:

```
./1.sh: 5: ./1.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "*"
```

This error occurs because the variables `$a` and `$b` doesn't get value form files `a` and `b`.

- If I `echo $a` and `echo $b` it returns nothing;
- If I define `a=22` and `b=12` values in the script it works;
- I also tried other ways of getting contents of files like `a=$(< 'a')`, `a=$(< "a")`, `a=$(< "~/a")`, and even `a=$(< cat a)`. None of those worked.

### Plot Twist:

However, if I change shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` so that **Bash shell** is used - it works.

### Question:

How to properly get data from file in **sh**?

Comment: Add output of `hexdump -C a` and `hexdump -C b` to your question.

Comment: `$(< file)` is a Bash extension. For POSIX sh, `$(cat file)` instead.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ would tell you "Warning (SC2039): In POSIX sh, $(<file) to read files is undefined." if you used the `#!/bin/sh` shebang.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore everything from file a and b but numbers:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=$(tr -cd 0-9 < a)
b=$(tr -cd 0-9 < b)
echo $(($a*$b))
```

---

See: `man tr`

Comment: Could also do just `echo $((a*b))`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. One obvious way is to pipe in a sub-process by **Command Substitution**:

```
A=$(cat fileA.txt)   # 22
B=$(cat fileB.txt)   # 12
echo $((A*B))
# <do it in your head!>
```

If there are any other problems with multiple lines, you need to look into how to use the Bash variable `$IFS` (*Internal File Separator*). Usually `IFS` is defined by: `IFS=$' \t\n'`, so if you need to be able to reliably read lines endings from both Windows and Linux EOL's  you may need to modify it.

---

**ADDENDUM:**

[**`Process Substitution`**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

> **Bash, Zsh**, and AT&T **ksh**{88,93} (but **not** *pdksh/mksh*) support process
>   substitution. Process substitution isn't specified by POSIX. You may
>   use NamedPipes to accomplish the same things. Coprocesses can also do
>   everything process substitutions can, and are slightly more portable
>   (though the syntax for using them is not).

This also means that most Android OS does not allow process substitution, since their shells are most often based on ***mksh***.

From **`man bash`**:

```
Process Substitution
   Process  substitution  allows  a process's input or output to be referred to using a filename.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The
   process list is run asynchronously, and its input or output appears as a filename.  This filename is passed as an  argument  to  the  current
   command  as  the result of the expansion.  If the >(list) form is used, writing to the file will provide input for list.  If the <(list) form
   is used, the file passed as an argument should be read to obtain the output of list.  Process substitution is supported on systems that  sup-
   port named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files.

   When  available, process substitution is performed simultaneously with parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic
   expansion.
```

Comment: Notice that process substitution (`<(...)`) isn't the same as command substitution (`$(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for "true" Bourne-Shell compatibility, as opposed to Bash's emulation, then you have to go old school:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=`cat a`
b=`cat b`
expr $a \* $b > c
```

I tried your original example under `#!/bin/sh` on both macOS and Linux (FC26), and it behaved properly, assuming `a` and `b` had UNIX line-endings.  If that can't be guaranteed, and you need to run under `#!/bin/sh` (as emulated by `bash`), then something like this will work:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=$(<a)
b=$(<b)
echo $(( ${a%%[^0-9]*} * ${b%%[^0-9]*} )) > c
```

Comment: Even the most ancient shells support command substitution with `$(...)` instead of backticks. You have to go back many decades to find one that doesn't. POSIX definitely supports it. On the other hand, even when `/bin/sh` is Bash, it does *not* support `$(<a)`.

Comment: To your first point, try /sbin/sh on Solaris 2.10.  To your second point, try /bin/sh on Fedora 26.